# mysql does not start after a reboot

Tags: server, mysql, upstart, 19.10

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 and installed mysql-server on it.
First it gave me an error

> error was mysql access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

solved by code below

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456';
```

based on an answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

I had rebooted the virtual machine now when I try to login

```
debian@osboxes:~$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I tried following

```
debian@osboxes:~$ mysql -u root -p 123456
Enter password: 
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '123456'
```

I want to know what mistake I am doing. I am trying to use mysql for some assignments is the above not the correct way to go to an sql prompt.
What else should I do?
I am using Ubuntu 19.10.

I don't have any idea of upstart echo system back in those days we used to have init scripts to start and stop daemons so I am browsing internet and it has become quite confusing what to do and what not to do. Like is the mysql service not available these days or what exactly I need to do to make sure after reboot mysql service is running. Which files should I check.

Comment: **Suggestion:** Never supply password in plain text. You can rather use `mysql -u root -p` to get a prompt for password.

Comment: Yes you are right I came to use sql after many many days so I have forgotten every thing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command syntax is wrong, this is why it is not working, get rid of the empty space between `-p` and your password.

```
mysql -u root -p123456
```