# Ubuntu 19.10 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: login, mysql, 19.10

First I did

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ mysql -u root -p

Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0     # version 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1, or
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.3  # version 1:10.3.20-0ubuntu0.19.10.1
```

then I installed

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0
```

Now I do

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

So now I check

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo service mysql status
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
```

then I do

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ ps aux | grep mysql
debian     4379  0.0  0.0   8896   916 pts/0    S+   14:38   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

so it seems mysql service is running. but when I Try to login now

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$
```

I also tried.

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ systemctl restart mysql
Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.

debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -l | grep -E 'mysql'
ii  libmysqlclient21:amd64                     8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1                 amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-client-core-8.0                      8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1                 amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                               5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2                        all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$
```

Last week 
I had asked question [mysql does not start after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201203/mysql-does-not-start-after-a-reboot) so I know I had installed mysql on this machine in problem. But still I face the problem so tried

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4531 (unattended-upgr) - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I also checked

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ systemctl -a | grep -iE 'mysql'
```

there was no output.
Also I do

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
sudo: netstat: command not found
```

then I do

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install net-tools
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

No output.

Now based on comments below I did

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

Now try

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Now I reboot 
and then

```
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ ps aux | grep mysql
debian     2403  0.0  0.0   8896   844 pts/0    S+   15:10   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

It is taking root password which I tried last week. I am not able to understand what should I check.
I can't login. What should I check now?
I am on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: In order to solve  the `E: Could not get lock` issue - take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: What is the result of running `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service`?

Comment: `failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
debian@osboxes:~/Desktop$ `

Comment: The error `Failed to restart mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.` seems to indicate that there is a problem with mysql server, if it was install on your machine

Comment: yes I did it mysql last week.

Comment: try to solve the `E: Could not get lock` issue - take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process) it should help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See terminal text. 'Waiting for cache lock' error. How to fix? I'm on Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352416/see-terminal-text-waiting-for-cache-lock-error-how-to-fix-im-on-ubuntu-21)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **mysql client** you need to install also **mysql server**.

I've added info from [Ubuntu mysql](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html)

**Installation**

To install MySQL, run the following command from a terminal prompt:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Once the installation is complete, the MySQL server should be started automatically. You can run the following command from a terminal prompt to check whether the MySQL server is running:

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

When you run this command, you should see the following line or something similar:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                LISTEN      2556/mysqld
```

If the server is not running correctly, you can type the following command to start it:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
```

**Configuration**

You can edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file to configure the basic settings -- log file, port number, etc. For example, to configure MySQL to listen for connections from network hosts, change the bind-address directive to the server's IP address:

```
bind-address            = 192.168.0.5
```

Replace `192.168.0.5` with the appropriate address.

After making a change to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` the MySQL daemon will need to be restarted:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
```

Comment: I updated the question please see if I have already included information which you wanted to suggest.